# How to take a substring using pattern match

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I have

```
String content= "<a data-hovercard=\"/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=180552688740185\">
                 <a data-hovercard=\"/ajax/hovercard/group.php?id=21392174\">"
```

I want to get all the id  between `"group.php?id="`   and    `"\""`

Ex:**180552688740185**

Here is my code:

```
String content1 = "";
Pattern script1 = Pattern.compile("group.php?id=.*?\"");
Matcher mscript1 = script1.matcher(content);
while (mscript1.find()) {
    content1 += mscript1.group() + "\n";
}
```

But for some reason it does not work.

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Try using String.match or String.split -- both take regex. this might help http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?292394-TIP-A-little-tutorial-about-String.split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `.*?` to match the `id`. `.*?` will match every character. You just need to check for `digits`. So, just use `\\d`.

Also, you need to capture the `id` and then print it.

```
// To consider special characters as literals
String str = Pattern.quote("group.php?id=") + "(\\d*)";

Pattern script1 = Pattern.compile(str);
// Your matcher line
while (mscript1.find()) {
    content += mscript1.group(1) + "\n";   // Capture group 1 contains your id
}
```

Comment: you also need to escape the `?` `Pattern.compile("group.php\\?id=(.*?)\"");`

Comment: I try that way too but the return string is still null.

Comment: @HirijiSakumo. Great. Just missed that `\\` thanks to Shyam that it got corrected. :)

Comment: regexp can be reduced to: "group.php\\?id=(\\d*)" to extract the whole number.

Comment: @Mik378 Oh yes.. Non-greedy quantifier is not needed here. :)

Comment: It's also probably a good idea to use `Pattern.quote()` for nontrivial literal segments in your RE. (Besides, it encourages you to store these segments in variables/constants with meaningful names, which never hurts.)

Comment: @RohitJain Don't quote the `(\d+)` part, you **want** those to be interpreted as metacharacters. Only the *literal* parts - the ones that will be in the original string verbatim. So something like this: `Pattern.quote("group.php?id=") + "(\\d*)";` (You can't get of double-backslashes, but you get out of quadruple-backslashing to match a literal `\`.)